# Active Record date range selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope

I'm trying to use a `scope` to pick up events occurring today, and in the next 7 days using their start dates and end dates (I'm also dealing with a timezone of UTC+7):

```
# scopes for date_start within 7 days on either side
t = Time.now.in_time_zone("Bangkok")
scope :seven_days, lambda { where("date_start <= ? AND date_start >= ?", t+7.days, t-7.days) }
```

So this picks up anything started in the last 7 days and starting in the next 7 days. But how can I also pick up something that is running from, say, 2 months ago and ends in 2 months? So it is still active in the coming 7 days (and today) but starts and ends outside of the scope?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have an attribute called `date_end`:

```
t = Time.now.in_time_zone("Bangkok")
scope :seven_days, lambda {
  where("date_start >= ? AND date_start <= ? OR
    date_start <= ? AND date_end >= ?",
    t-7.days, t+7.days, t-7.days, t+7.days)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabian_Winkler. Could you explain the logic behind this? I don't understand how the OR is working here.

Comment: So let's use parentheses to make the logic more obvious:
`(date_start ≥ ? AND date_start ≤ ?) OR (date_start ≤ ? AND date_end ≥ ?)`
The first part selects all events that started within the last 7 days or will start within next 7 days.
The second part will select all events that started more than 7 days ago und will end in more than 7 days.
The `OR` operator, also known as logical disjunction, joins both subsets.